# Difference between as? Type and as Type?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, casting, null, annotations

I'm having issues figuring out the difference between these two statements.

The first one makes use of the as? operator to cast the generic annotation class to XYZ

```
this::class.annotations.find { it is XYZ } as? XYZ ?: return
```

And the second one makes use of the as? operator and of the null marker

```
this::class.annotations.find { it is XYZ } as XYZ? ?: return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you use safe casting (as?) to not-nullable type XYZ. If `it` is instance of XYZ, then it will just cast `it` to XYZ. If `it` is not instance of XYZ (or if `it` is null), then it will return null.

In the second case, you use unsafe casting (as) to nullable type XYZ?. If `it` is instance of XYZ or `it` is null, then it will cast `it` to XYZ? (or return null, if `it` is null). If `it` is not instance of XYZ, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As I know

`this::class.annotations.find { it is XYZ } as? XYZ`

value cast XYZ is not null but value checked null before cast

`this::class.annotations.find { it is XYZ } as XYZ?`

value cast XYZ is nullable and check null after cast